after upload a new version of compressed revit+textures files , viewer shows always the first version
we made an application that upload Revit files in a Forge bucket to show in another web app with the Forge Viewer: when we re-upload a new version of the Revit file, the viewer correctly show the new version.
Now we've decide to add textures to the Revide model so, following this article https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/show-revit-custom-texture-map-viewer of Eason Kang, we upload a zip file with all the textures and the revit file, and it works fine, all materials ara shown correctly.
ie: TEST.RVT + MAT1.JPG + MAT2.JPG -> TEST.ZIP
The problem is that, if we upload a new version of the Revit file, always inside a zip, both with the same old name, the viewer shows always the first version of the revit file.
I always force a new translation on the same file using the x-ads-force = true.
I tried also to first delete the old zip file and then upload the new version, but the problem persist: the strange behaviuor is that, if I delete the old zip, then open the viewer with the old URN, without upload the new version, the old revit is shown as I didn't delete it (I verified and the zip is not present in the bucket).
I find a "bad" workaround that works, naming the zip file univocly, while the Revit inside has the old name (ie: TEST.RVT + MAT1.JPG + MAT2.JPG -> TEST_20241003120000.ZIP) , but this cause the bucket to have a lot of old files\versions now unused.

Have you tried to clear the web browser cache?
